# How to execute a function when an uncaught error occurred at application level

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to execute a function whenever a uncaught error occured at application level. Is it possible to do like that or I have to write try catch at all my controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has a built-in error handler service called [`$exceptionHandler`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler) which can easily be overriden as seen below:

```
myApp.factory('$exceptionHandler', function($log, ErrorService) {
    return function(exception, cause) {

        if (console) {
            $log.error(exception);
            $log.error(cause);
        }

        ErrorService.send(exception, cause);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the *$exceptionHandler* service. This allows you to override what the default behaviour of uncaught exceptions.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler